# How to convert reading ADC Value to Float?

Tags: c, stm32, data-conversion, adc

I want to convert ADC Values to float numbers. 
This is my code:

```
uint32_t ADCValue;
char str[15];

          ADCValue = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
          ADCValue=ADCValue*3.3/4095;
          sprintf(str, "%d", Voltage);
          HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*)(&str), 6, 100);
          HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*) "\n\r", 2, 100);
          HAL_Delay(500);
```

I am reading value of 4095 at 3.3V but I am transmitting 3 to buffer. I want to transmit exact value of voltage.

Comment: `ADCValue=ADCValue*3.3/4095` -->  `ADCValue=(ADCValue*10)*33/40950`

Comment: What is `Voltage`?

Comment: @LPs - why the extra multiplication by 10? 3.3 was already changed to 33.

Comment: Do you want to transmit the float value on UART?

Comment: @4386427 To move a decimal into integer part.

Comment: @LPs - I see... So instead of sending the truncated value `3`, it will be `33`. Nice idea in case floats are not an option.

Comment: @4386427 I guessed it's an embedded platform, so better to work with int instead of float. ;)

Comment: @Lps I am reading  33 instead of 3.3 . I think this is not exact solution.

Comment: @Dummy You send 33 but you know how to "decode it" on the slave device.

Comment: @Dummy ... or you can transform `33` to `3.3` yourself by some simple string manipulations.

Comment: @Dummy just to eliminate all possible misunderstandings: which string do you want to transmit for `ADCValue = 3457` ?

Comment: @RishikeshRaje Yes, Isn't it possible ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz If ADCValue=3457,I should read 3457*3.3/4095= 2.78.I want to read 2.78 Volt.

Comment: Since you don't appear to be doing any advanced math calculations, why do you need float numbers to begin with? Does you MCU even have a FPU?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no apparent reason why you need to use float numbers here in the first place. They are needlessly slow. Simply do this:

```
uint32_t millivolts = ADCValue*3300/4095.
```

For an input of 4095, you get the result 3299mV. This is possibly more accurate than what you would get through float numbers, because of floating-point inaccuracy.

Comment: While I agree that floats are not necessary here, there is no reason why they would be less accurate here. Unless you back it up with something, this answer would be better of without such remark.

Comment: In case of using CMSIS DSP float functions we have to convert ADC output to float. This is bad and make ADC DMA useless, What if hardware could output float directly.

Answer (score 5):

You probably want this:

```
ADCValue = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
float fADCValue = (float)ADCValue*3.3 / 4095.0;
int txlength = sprintf(str, "%.2f", fADCValue);
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*)(&str), txlength, 100);
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*) "\n\r", 2, 100);
HAL_Delay(500);
```

Caution: this only works if the `float` type is available on your platform.

If floating point is not available you can use this:

```
ADCValue = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
ADCValue = ADCValue * 330 / 4095;
int len = sprintf(str, "%d.%02d", ADCValue / 100, ADCValue % 100);
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*)(&str), leb, 100);
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*) "\n\r", 2, 100);
```

This is a quick hack and there is certainly room for improvement.

Demonstration [here](http://ideone.com/KXutuM).

Comment: My platform may not be available for float type.

Comment: @Dummy see my updated answer. Now there is a solution for the case where floating point math is not available on your platform.

Comment: @MichaelWalz It worked.Now I am reading in float number.Thanks man.

Comment: @4386427 good idea, answer updated. But still could not spot any other decimals related problems.

Comment: You need to have the `02` in format string for decimals: http://ideone.com/RBJCmn

Comment: @Dummy the program was not quite correct, the answer has been corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
float Adcvalue_f;
uint32_t ADCValue;
char str[15];
....
ADCValue = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1); 
ADCValue_f =ADCValue*3.3/4095;
sprintf(str, "%2.2f", AdcValue_f);   //Adjust the .2 as per required precision
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*)(&str), 6, 100);
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*) "\n\r", 2, 100);
```

Comment: With this code,I am reading just empty data :) What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: empty data at other UART or at `str`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other fine answers, consider:

Integer division truncates the factional part of the mathematical quotient.

Instead, perform a *rounded* integer division.  With unsigned integer math, add half the divisor before the division.

```
// ADCValue=ADCValue*3.3/4095;

unsigned Voltage = // millivolts
Voltage = (ADCValue*3300 + 4095/2)/4095.
```